# How to get django-compress and s3cmd working together

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-compressor

At job we're using s3cmd to send our staticfiles to S3. The workflow is:

```
1) collectstatic to a local folder
2) s3cmd into that folder to our S3 bucket
```

We're trying now to use django-compress, so now our workflow is:

```
1) compress to STATIC_ROOT folder
2) collectstatic (images, fonts etc.)
3) s3cmd to the S3 bucket
```

The reason we're not using django-storages as recommended by compressor is that we had some troubles with CSS. Surprinsingly, some css rules are missing in compressed files, no matter
what compressing solution we use.

```
OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key
"d345e38725a478c7db70d8e23d4c771b" is missing from offline manifest. 
You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

The full traceback can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/lucassmagal/5751025). Does anyone know what's happening here? Suggestions to improve our *compress and upload* workflow are very welcome.